# Passing 'start' from django url gives error "start() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) "

Tags: python, django, django-urls

unfortunately i am getting a unexpected error in Django.
I have a this urls :

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
            url(r'', include('ads.urls',namespace="ads")),
    )
    urlpatterns += patterns('ads.search',
            url(r'^getsubcategories/$', 'getsubcategories', name="getsubcategories"),
            url(r'^anuncios/([\w\-]+)/$', 'anuncios_search', name="anuncios_search"),
            url(r'^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/$', 'search',name="search_text"),
            url(r'^([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)/$', 'ads_details',name="ads_details"),
    )
```

When I am going to call url  "anuncios_search" this will work for all search patterns accept "/anuncios/start/", please see below for working urls:

examples:

1) /anuncios/avc/ : this works.

2) /anuncios/finds/: this works .

3) /anuncios/start-day/: this works .

4) /anuncios/starts/: this works .

5) /anuncios/start/: this url throwing me error :

```
Internal Server Error: /anuncios/start/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yogesh/ENV/munda/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: start() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
[13/Nov/2014 05:36:57] "GET /anuncios/start/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11496
```

my views.py is :

```
def anuncios_search(request,search_text=None):
    """
    This method for home page search, for acept contactos category
    """
    if search_text:
        search_text_list = [i for i in search_text.split("-") if len(i)>2]
    else:
        search_text_list=[]

    ads = Ad.objects.exclude(subcategory__category__adult=True,user__is_active=True).order_by('-active','-republishDate')
    if search_text_list:
        ads = ads.filter(
            reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(title__icontains=word) for word in search_text_list])|
            reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(description__icontains=word) for word in search_text_list])
            ).order_by('-active','-republishDate')

    current_filters= {'current_category':None,'ads':ads_paginator(request,ads)}
    current_filters['search_text'] = search_text and " ".join(search_text.split("-")) or None
    current_filters['search_text_list'] = search_text_list and search_text_list or None
    return render(request,'search/search.html',current_filters)
```

Please help me to resolve this bug.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please try to give me ANS in English please ?

Comment: it seems that start is defined elsewhere (even imported) in your urls, can you check it?

Comment: start is not define any where in whole project as well I only imported patterns in urls.py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As xecgr said, there must be another view or function (named start) which is somehow getting imported and used. Maybe in some other module imported on your INSTALLED_APPS... Maybe there is some kind of pattern which uses a regex and calls a view named after this matching word? ... who knows. It's definitely weird.

Maybe the problem arises because you're looking for views for this patterns on the whole ads.search module and thus leading to this unexpected results. Why don't you try the following:

Instead of doing:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('ads.search',
    url(r'^getsubcategories/$', 'getsubcategories', name="getsubcategories"),
    url(r'^anuncios/([\w\-]+)/$', 'anuncios_search', name="anuncios_search"),
)
```

try:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('ads.search.views',
    url(r'^getsubcategories/$', 'getsubcategories', name="getsubcategories"),
    url(r'^anuncios/([\w\-]+)/$', 'anuncios_search', name="anuncios_search"),
)
```

Which should restrict your urls to the views listed on your views.py file listed above.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then please post your whole imports at the beginning of urls.py.

Another thing you could try, is look for the pattern/view named start. For this, you can try:

```
pip install django-extensions
```

Then add `django_extensions` to your INSTALLED_APPS. And then just use the following command to list all urls and their views in the project:

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

or, if they are too many and the start view does exist somewhere, this should work:

```
python manage.py show_urls | grep start
```

Comment: Hi, @andzep, I did as you mention and nothing found there is no url with name 'start' and also i replace from "views.py" to 'search.py' search.py is file where method exist. I edited mu urls.py and  accept I dont have any url, and admin urls will start from admin so i think that will not effect.

Comment: Did you looked through the list of urls from the `show_urls` command? Is there an url with some kind of regex, that might match the `anuncios` part as a parameter and then `start` with another regex in a second paramter, and then use it to call a view named after that parameter?  I'm thinking of some kind of weird cms-app, something like flatpages or such which would call a view based on that second parameter. Which, is quite unprobable, I know. But maybe it's more than a coincidence that anuncios/start tries to call a view also named start. So this might be worth following.

Comment: ... also, the urlpattern catching this, must be before `anuncios_search` or else, it would be taking that view. So, this is coming either from your ads.urls patterns or from some patterns installed in the INSTALLED_APPS.  Can you post the patterns in `ads.urls.py` too?  And if the list is not tooo long, can you list the url-listing from `show_urls` too?

Comment: Hi Yogesh, as you accepted my answer, I guess you finally found the problem. Can you comment what was it?  Was it the <regex>/<regex> pattern calling dynamically a view?

Comment: I fix this issue for now. i just palce a url  '/anuncios/start/' begning of urls.py file. now this start working. later i will fix this issue. but your suggestion get help full to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have another `urlpattern` for `/anuncios/start/` (not in the current `urls.py`), and the `start` method there takes two arguments. If that is the case, and its priority is higher than your current urlpattern with the regex, the error will be thrown.

So either remove that urlpattern, or handle its parsing logic in your `def anuncios_search()` with extra code.

***Edit***

To debug this, simplify your code.

1. Check what happens if you alter the `anuncios_search` method to only `render` a text string. If it still throws the same error, we know the issue is with url parsing.

   - You might not have defined a `urlpattern` yourself, but this could be some plugin which you use that does this. in that case, if you are using plugins, try removing them one by one if possible.
2. If it doesn't, then use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the first line of your `anuncios_search` method. Make the request again, and then you will be able to find out the exact place of exception.

***Edit 2 - More investigation***

I am not sure if you are using [Django 1.5](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/core/handlers/base.py#L114), but from its source code, it is apparent  that the exception raised in a view is passed through the middlewares for responses, and if not, then the appropriate error is raised.

In your case, you are using code

```
current_filters= {'current_category':None,'ads':ads_paginator(request,ads)}
```

which I think could be the psosible statement raising an unhandled exception.

Comment: I dont have any urls start from "/anuncios/*" and also I don't have any url or method name "start" in my whole project.

Comment: @Yogesh Since there is no additional information yet, can you update with the debug statements mentioned in my edits?

Comment: I have given trace in my questing I am only getting those.and when i am going to hit page, before request come into my method exception get raise.